# Как расположить объект внизу экрана?

Tags: android, java, canvas

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Мне нужно на canvas отрисовать картинку внизу экрана и по центру, как это лучше и правильней сделать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Определить размер экрана
2. Определить размер картинки
3. Отступ слева = ширина_экрана / 2 - ширина_картинки / 2
4. Отступ сверху = высота_экрана - высота_картинки
5. [Нарисовать картинку](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20draw%20bitmap%20on%20canvas&es_th=1).

Comment: Спасибо, но вы не могли бы написать, как реализовать определение размера картинки.

Comment: @lenochka727, гугл знает. именно так у него и спросите.